# Close DIV from another html page with return value

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

I have a php web page which has a textbox. beside the textbox i have provided a link. On clicking a link DIV open which has a ifram. I frame is populated with a list of items with id and description. Now when I click a particular Item I want the DIV to get closed and ID of that particular item to be fetched into the textbox.

```
Page1.php

<html>
<body>


<input id="productid" type="text" name="productID" />
        <img src=search.gif border=1 onclick="document.all.floatDiv.style.display='inline'" alt="Expand">
        <img src=nosearch.gif onclick="document.all.floatDiv.style.display='none'" alt="Compress">

        <div id="floatDiv">
            <iframe name="moreIframe" id="moreIframe" width="99%" height="97%" align="center" src="Page2.php" style="background-color: white;"></iframe>
            <?php
            ?>
        </div>

</body>
</html>

Page2.php

<html>
<body>

<table>
    <tr>
        <td>ID</td>
        <td>Product</td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
        <td><a href="" onclick="retvalue('12')" >12</a></td>
        <td>Brass 13 mm Rod</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td><a href="" onclick="retvalue('15')" >15</a></td>
        <td>Steel 13 mm Rod</td>
    </tr>
<table>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: A little too general to get useful feedback here. Might want to provide some code of what you have so far.

Comment: And what is the problem!?

Comment: See the added code. I want 12 or 15 from the page 2 to be filled in the page1 textbox productid

Comment: where have you created the `retvalue()` function?

Comment: i have not created the retvalue() function yet. I want help in that only

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer as below.

Page1.php

```
<html>
<style>
#floatDiv {
    position:absolute;
    left:50%;
    margin-top:200px;
    margin-left:-200px;
    width:600px;
    height:200px;
    background-color: blue;
    display:none;
}
</style>

<script language="javascript">
function closediv()
{
    document.getElementById('floatDiv').style='none';
}
</script>
<body>

<form name="form1" id="form2" method="post" >

<input id="productid" type="text" name="productID" />
        <img src=search.gif border=1 onclick="document.all.floatDiv.style.display='inline'" alt="Expand">
        <img src=nosearch.gif onclick=" closediv();" alt="Compress">


        <div id="floatDiv">
            <iframe name="moreIframe" id="moreIframe" width="99%" height="97%" align="center" src="Page2.php?fldnm=productID" style="background-color: white;"></iframe>
            <?php
            ?>
        </div>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

and page2.php

```
<html>
<head>
<script language="javascript">
function CloseWin(varv,elem)
{
    parent.document.forms['form1'].elements[elem].value=varv;
    parent.closediv();

}   
</script>
</head>
<body>
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>ID</td>
        <td>Product</td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
        <td><a class='test' href="" id="id1" onclick="kickass('12','productID');">12</a></td>
        <td>Brass 13 mm Rod</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td><a href="" class='test'  onclick="kickass('15','productID');">15</a></td>
        <td>Steel 13 mm Rod</td>
    </tr>
<table>

<html>
<body>
```

It does close the div containing the iframe and passed value in the textbox productID.

Answer (score 0):

Step1:In this http://demos.jquerymobile.com/1.4.0/popup-iframe/ create ifream code
Launch video player

Step2: in ifream fatch data from database

Step3: on click fatched data call ajax and close ifream

step4: on click data fatch $_REQUEST method throw call value

Answer (score 0):

Replace the content of Page2.php file with following

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>ID</td>
        <td>Product</td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
        <td><a class='test' href="" >12</a></td>
        <td>Brass 13 mm Rod</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td><a href="" class='test' >15</a></td>
        <td>Steel 13 mm Rod</td>
    </tr>
<table>
<script>
var classname = document.getElementsByClassName("test");

 for(var i=0;i<classname.length;i++){

        classname[i].addEventListener("click", function(event){
    event.preventDefault();
      var attribute = this.innerText;
      alert(attribute);
      window.parent.document.getElementById('productid').value = attribute;
});
}

</script>
```

Comment: after I click the 12 or 15 link text box has "undefined" text as content and the div still remain open.

Comment: Does alert() retur proper value?